# Safe to use UTF8 decoding for EXIF property marked as ASCII?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, exif

I received an image file with EXIF ImageDescription metadata having a value of "Test accents: éâäàè". When using the .NET GDI+ classes for extracting this data, it reports that it is stored as ASCII but I get garbage data when using the ASCII decoder. Through trial and error, I discovered I can extract it correctly using the UTF8 decoder.

Here is sample code:

```
public string GetDescription()
{
  const string filePath = @"C:\test_image.jpg";

  using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(filePath))
  {
    var propItem = bmp.PropertyItems.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 270); // EXIF ImageDescription

    if (propItem == null)
      return null;

    string value = null;

    if (propItem.Type == 2) // ASCII
    {
      // Does not work: Returns "Test accents: ??????????"
      var asciiEnc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
      value = asciiEnc.GetString(propItem.Value, 0, propItem.Value.Length - 1);

      // CORRECT: Returns "Test accents: éâäàè"
      var utf8Enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
      value = utf8Enc.GetString(propItem.Value, 0, propItem.Value.Length - 1);
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

I am considering changing my production code so that I always use the UTF8 decoder when extracting meta properties even though PropertyItem.Type indicates it is ASCII. It certainly works in this case but I'm throwing this out to you folks in case there is an unforeseen consequence I am missing.

So - is it a bad idea to using the UTF8 decoder when extracting ASCII metadata?

PS: I also tried extracting the data with the BitmapMetadata class using the following code and got incorrect results. If there is a reliable way to use this technique instead I am open to it.

```
// Returns incorrect string: "Test accents: Ã©Ã¢Ã¤Ã Ã¨"
var value = bitmapMetadata.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/{ushort=270}") as string;
```

Comment: Accents aren't valid `ASCII`, more than likely it is being represented as `ISO-8859-1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot get it reliable.  Exif suffers from the common encoding misery, the Exif standard dictates that only 7-bit ASCII codes should be used but everybody ignores it.  They have to, ASCII just can't properly encode text in many languages.  Pretty remarkable btw, Exif comes from Japan, a country with a language that has very little use for ASCII and a [rich history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) of encoding problems.  So everybody just picks whatever encoding suits them, could be UTF8 or could be ANSI, whatever code page is in common use where the image was created.

Between a rock and a hard place, using UTF8Encoding is the best choice.  It is not going to deal well with text that was encoded in an ANSI code page, there's just isn't much you can do about it.  Encoding.Default is a poor second choice.  The text in your image is in fact utf-8 encoded.

But yes, if the text is actually pure ASCII then UTF8Encoding will work fine.  Utf-8 encodes the ASCII codes the same way.

Comment: I guess the reason why EXIF has these arcane restrictions, is that it is really the TIFF format, which is really old. They still *could* have made the choice of using a different data type than ASCII and define the charset as UTF8 though...

Comment: Don't even suggest ANSI encoding or other nonsense. Please, everybody, use UTF8 only for anything which goes to disk (or on wire).

Comment: Encoders should write non-ascii text into the "XP" fields (XPTitle, XPSubject etc) instead which take UCS-2 encoding. Or use the "UserComment" field  which has the encoding used written into the first 8 bytes

Answer (score 0):

[IPTC standard](http://www.iptc.org/cms/site/index.html?channel=CH0089) has [`Iptc.Envelope.CharacterSet`](http://www.exiv2.org/iptc.html) so that in [jbrout](https://code.google.com/p/jbrout/) (which is in Python) we [do](https://code.google.com/p/jbrout/source/browse/trunk/jbrout/jbrout/pyexiv.py#49)

```
self._md["Iptc.Envelope.CharacterSet"] = ['\x1b%G', ]
```

And of course I believe that everybody should use UTF8 only for anything which goes to disk (or on wire). Using ANSI encoding (or however it is called in that other operating system from Microsoft) should be punishable as an offense.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about EXIF, not IPTC. On top of that old documents just don't cease to exist because UTF-8 has emerged - one still wants to parse them.